# Appending a style tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to build a basic chatroom on my site using socket.io. I have the base functionality working, but I want to bold one of my input fields. I've tried variations on

```
$('#messages').append($('<li>').text('<strong>'+msg.user+': </strong>'+msg.message));
```

and it just ends up appending, literally `<strong>`. How should I format this to actually bold 'msg.user'?

Comment: use .html  not .text

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `.text`, try using the `.html`

Answer (score 0):

you can use .html() instead .text()

```
$("#messages").append( $("<div>").html("<strong>" + msg.user + "</strong>" + msg.message));
```